# How to get a max string length in nested lists

Tags: python

They is a follow up question to my earlier post (re printing table from a list of lists)

I'm trying t get a string max value of the following nested list:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

for i in tableData:
    print(len(max(i)))
```

which gives me 7, 5, 5. But "cherries" is 8

what a my missing here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You've done the *length of the maximum word*.  This gives the wrong answer because words are ordered [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order):

```
>>> 'oranges' > 'cherries'
True
```

What you probably wanted is the *maximum of the lengths of words*:

```
max(len(word) for word in i)
```

Or equivalently:

```
len(max(i, key=len))
```

Comment: just curious, how do i also print out the max string as well as as max length for each element? Thanks

Comment: I tried this- print(i[2], len(max(i, key=len))) but that doesn't really work

Comment: Since `len(max(i, key=len))` gives you the length of the longest word, it's easy to see that `max(i, key=len)` gives you the longest word.

Answer (score 1):

In string operations `max` will Return the maximum alphabetical character from the string, not in basics of length. So you have to do something like this.

```
len(max(sum(tableData,[]),key=len))
```

`sum(tableData,[])` will convert the `list of list` to `list` this helps to iterate through the list of list.

Length in each row

```
In [1]: [len(max(i,key=len)) for i in tableData]
Out[1]: [8, 5, 5]
```

See the difference,

```
In [2]: max(sum(tableData,[]))
Out[2]: 'oranges'
In [3]: max(sum(tableData,[]),key=len)
Out[3]: 'cherries'
```

Comment: I didn't DV you, but the user wanted the max length in each row - not over the whole table.  Also, joining lists with `sum` is needlessly inefficient and most people prefer using a comprehension or a [chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) for that.

Comment: @wim That's true, People prefer comprehension only, that is the most efficient method. i just used `sum` because it's a small purpose. And i updated my answer for each row length finding. And thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score -1):

You were printing the length of the max element in each row. Python computes the `max` string element as the one that is seen last in a dictionary (lexicographic sorting). What you want instead is `max(len(s) for s in i)` instead of `len(max(i))`

```
for row in tableData:
    print(max(len(s) for s in row))
```

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I want the max string length from each element in the nested list. So expected to see: 8, 5,5.